# Disable edit options from macro enabled Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I've recently created a tool via excel using vba and macros to sort text and I would like to save it a way that when a user opens it, he will not have access to the files ribbons and he will not be given an option to edit the file or the workbook.

I've already protected the cells and converted it to read only but still the user is given an option to enable editing and what not.

I've found `Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"` but it affects all other workbooks. Is there a way to do this on a specific workbook alone? Like

```
If Activeworkbooks = Specificworkbook.xlsm Then
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
End IF
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!  I've used this particular trick many times...Essentially you will be editing the XML of the ribbon.  See [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm) and [here](http://www.contextures.com/excelribbonaddcustomtab.html) for instructional tutorials.  It will involve downloading the editor, but once that is done you can edit the ribbon of a single file and it won't effect other files.  It's a great way to "lock" down a file to allow end users to only do what you as the developer want them to.